# How can async only work on one thread?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

If some code 'await's and the single thread carries on running a program, how can the bit that's been paused come back to life? Does the single thread need to go back a poll the state of the paused bit of code to see if its finished?

Comment: Generally waits are resumed from ThreadPool threads as that is where most async IO operations usually end up running their callback.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. Do you have a sample code you don't understand to show ?

Comment: I don't understand any async code. It doesn't make sense. If I have some code that awaits on a file being loaded, how does the thread know when the file has finished loading?

Comment: Have you read [Asynchronous Programming with Async and Await](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh191443.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1)? It pretty much answers what you are asking.

Comment: The different threads can synchronize, for example, using signals (Monitor.Wait() and Monitor.Pulse()). Pretty much, the thread "agree" on a memory location to watch, and react to its changes.

Comment: @James I don't think that articles answers the question. It does  hint at the answer with the following cryptic statement, 'The method runs on the current synchronization context and uses time on the thread only when the method is active.'

Answer (score 3):

Both the [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh191443.aspx) and my [introductory `async` blog post](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) answer this.

In summary, when an `async` method encounters an `await` for an operation that is not yet completed, then by default it will capture the current context. This "context" is the current `SynchronizationContext`, unless it is `null`, in which case it is the current `TaskScheduler`. Later, when the operation completes, the remainder of the `async` method is scheduled to that context.

In UI apps, this can be a UI `SynchronizationContext` (scheduling the method on the UI thread). In ASP.NET apps, this is usually a request context (which is not bound to a specific thread). If you're running an `async` method on the thread pool, it's usually the thread pool context (again, not bound to any specific thread).

Returning to the UI example, the UI thread does have a central "message loop" that it runs, processing Win32 messages from its queue. The UI `SynchronizationContext` simply posts a message to the queue telling the UI thread to execute the next part of the `async` method.

Comment: +1 I've read most of your blog posts on `async` and can only recommend them, although I think you do not insist enough on the central role of `SynchronizationContext` (which you do in this answer!)

Answer (score 1):

> [...] how can the bit that's been paused come back to life?

By using a delegate (taken from [msdn](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/04/12/10293335.aspx)).

> The “await” keyword tells the compiler to insert a possible
> suspension/resumption point into a method marked as “async”.
>
> Logically this means that when you write “await someObject;” the
> compiler will generate code that checks whether the operation
> represented by someObject has already completed. If it has, execution
> continues synchronously over the await point. If it hasn’t, the
> generated code will hook up a continuation delegate to the awaited
> object such that when the represented operation completes, that
> continuation delegate will be invoked. This continuation delegate will
> re-enter the method, picking up at this await location where the
> previous invocation left off. At this point, regardless of whether the
> awaited object had already completed by the time it was awaited, any
> result from the object will be extracted, or if the operation failed,
> any exception that occurred will be propagated.

---

> Does the single thread need to go back a poll the state of the paused bit of code to see if its finished?

No, there is no such thing. When you call `await` the control from the current thread goes one step up the call-stack, ie it is returned to the callee of the method that contains `await`. When the task is finished, TPL calls a delegate method, which resumes control from the `await` line.

Comment: It's task parallel library, it used to be a separate assembly but now it is part of the .NET framework, C# compiler and CLR.

Answer (score 0):

I actually don't know specifically how `await` is implemented in C#, but let me propose a way it *could* be, just to answer the question "How is it possible?" (as opposed to "How is it implemented"?).

First consider the `yield` keyword, which is completely different but, I think, more generally understood. When you write a function that returns `IEnumerable<T>` and use `yield return` within the body of the function, most of us by now understand that the C# compiler *generates an iterator class for you*, and produces IL that looks very different from the code you wrote. My point being that we must realize the C# code itself does not always map very clearly to a set of IL instructions; sometimes the transformation is complex.

Such must also be the case with `await`, where the C# compiler doesn't simply emit a bunch of simple steps for each line of C# code. What it could do instead, for example, is take the call with `await`, generate a delegate that calls the given method, and then bundle up the *rest* of the method's code as a callback to the delegate.

How that *other method* operates asynchronously is immaterial to the `await` keyword. It might execute work on a separate thread, or perform some I/O operations. Whatever it does, it must conform to the asynchronous pattern of returning a `Task<T>`; this is what `await` relies on.

The resulting function, in IL, would then return, after having added the remaining logic as a listener to receive a signal when the work taking place on the separate thread is completed. That separate thread would then post a message back to the original thread (which, in most scenarios, will actually be a message loop), along with a reference to the listener.

Comment: 'a delegate that executes the given work on a separate (probably pooled) thread' - that's exactly what its supposed to not do!

Comment: @IanWarburton: You're right, I worded things poorly. It's the other method--the thing you call `await` *with*--that might (in many cases, probably does) create a new thread, not the `await` keyword itself. But except in cases of I/O, the work is almost certainly going to happen on another thread. I will update this answer.